# Extends Interface NodeJS

Tags: node.js, typescript, interface, extends

I have an Interface :

```
interface MyInterface {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  ...
}
```

I want to extends it in a forEach :

```
AllData.forEach((extendsInterface: MyInterface extends { newVar: string }) => {
   extendsInterface.newVar = "Hello World";
}
```

I have this error :  `'?' Expected` on the `)` after `{ newVar: string }`

Don't know what i'm doing wrong
Thanks !

**EDIT :**

If i create `MyInterfaceExt` outside the line, or use`&` instead of `extends` i have this error :

```
Argument of type '(extendsInterface: MyInterfaceExt) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: MyInterface, index: number, array: MyInterface[]) => void'.
Types of parameters 'extendsInterface' and 'value' are incompatible.
Property 'newVar' is missing in type 'MyInterface' but required in type 'MyInterfaceExt'
```

Comment: You should use `&` instead of `extends` to create "inline" intersection type

Comment: Otherwise `interface MyInterfaceExt extends MyInterface { newVar: string }` and use it to type the argument

Comment: @AlekseyL. why don't you answer it?

Comment: @AlekseyL. I Edit my post, ty

Comment: It's happen because new properties (extended) are _required_. Sulution: use `newVar` as _optional_ parameter, like `MyInterface & { newVar?: string }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in comments you can choose between:

```
interface MyInterfaceExt extends MyInterface { 
  newVar?: string;
}
```

or if you wish to add inline, called [intersection-type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types)

```
MyInterface & { newVar?: string }
```